# Bluetooth - NFC communcation

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth, nfc

I want to build a device that would recieve a NFC TAG and send it via Bluetooth to the Mobile Phone, that has Bluetooth enabled.

I am searching for some basic articles or some starting points on how to accomplish this.

I am thinking that I'll need some sort of uController that will transfer the bytes between NFC chip and Bluetooth Module. 
But I don't know how to proceed on this step.

Any advice would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be very easy with an Arduino + NFC (or RFID) reader/shield + Bluetooth module/shield.

Here is a cheap NFC reader (based on the [MFRC522](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MFRC522.pdf) chip) from ebay ~$6 [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/MFRC-522-RC522-RFID-Radiofrequency-IC-Card-Inducing-Sensor-Reader-for-Arduino-M5-/251715996308?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a9b714a94) and it uses SPI for communication, also here is a blog post that shows how to use it with an arduino [link](http://www.grantgibson.co.uk/2012/04/how-to-get-started-with-the-mifare-mf522-an-and-arduino/)

for the bluetooth, the easiest way is to use a serial module like [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Wireless-Serial-4-Pin-Bluetooth-RF-Transceiver-Module-HC-06-Slave-for-Arduino-/390980110841?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5b083b09f9) ~$5 just google "arduino + HC-06" and you will find many results showing how to use it.

then you need to write the code that read data from SPI and sends it over serial.

---

Update:

here is another NFC reader (based on the same chip MFRC522) [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/UART-RS232-TTL-RFID-13-56-MHz-Mifare-RC522-ISO14443A-for-Mifare1-S50-S70-Arduino-/131317634853) but the module exposes the serial pins UART instead of SPI, so technically you can wire this directly to the bluetooth module (RX-->TX and TX-->RX) but you need to match the baudrate and other serial settings between the two

Some bluetooth modules can be programmed over serial (simple commands to change default settings like Name, PIN code and speed) but i have used one that didn't allow me to change default speed (9600).

also check to make sure voltages match 5v or 3.3v or use something like a voltage divider.

Comment: FAD thank you for your answer - this will surely be my basis on this project!
I was thinking which control to choose, but somehow (for the first time ever) Arduino didn't pop to my head!

With your exaplanation sounds quite simple to do this. Hopefully, it'll be. I'm doing it for a school project.

Comment: Check my update regarding the UART module, you might not need an arduino ;)

Comment: me again :) I was just wondering, if I can use some other uC for this or does it have to be Arduino for that NFC Reader and Bluetooth Module ? My professor is not a fan of Arduino, he says, that you don't learn any real electronic software development with it, because it has in-built libraries that help you out. :)

Comment: of course you can use any uC, I just suggested the Arduino because as you professor said it is easy and many things are already implemented for you like the SPI protocol. However, you can use an arduino board but program it using Avr-C or assembly since the arduino is simply an Atmel ATMega uC with a very simple to use programming language

Comment: I have Arduino UNO now at my home, But as I was about to order [NFC Shield](http://www.adafruit.com/product/789) and  [Bluetooth Module](http://learning.grobotronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/board.jpg) .. I noticed that, NFC shield takes all of my PINs on UNO..how can I possibly connect the Bluetooth Module to Arduino if there are no PINs left?

Comment: Most shields uses only certain ports (e.g. SPI ports like 13, 12, 11,10 ) and connections to the other ports are not used so you can connect to them from the shield itself. Even some (depending on the protocol used) allow sharing the same ports. e.g. SPI can be used by many devices either in a chain or by using SS (slave select)

Comment: So your bluetooth uses UART/serial (port D0 and D1) as shown in the picture, keep in mind that these ports are also used during the programming of the arduino itself. so you need to make sure the bluetooth is not sending anything to the arduino during programming, or to be safe just unplug it, or use softwareserial which emulate UART on any port you like.

Comment: And for the NFC shield, if you read the last part on the page you linked, it says that it by default uses I2C protocol, so that means it is only connected to the analog ports A4 (SDA), A5 (SCL). You can change it to use SPI or UART, but I2C should be good so it won't conflict with other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for answers, will have a look now into ordering. It's good that you keep visiting this site, because I'm sure I'll need some help. Do you think I should order the above mentioned components for my project? Or are there better options in your opinion ?

Comment: The NFC you linked too is too expensive (the extra features that it has are not implemented), I personally will use the one in my first link, it works over SPI and also comes with two NFC tags that you can use for testing and also it is very cheap.